# Is there a better way to monitor log files?(linux/python)

Tags: python, linux, logging

I'm trying to monitor log files that some process are running on linux(to create a joint log file where log entries are grouped together by when they happen). Currently I'm thinking of opening the files being logged, polling with inotify(or wrapper) and then checking if I can read any more of the file.

Is there any better way to do this? Perhaps some library which abstracts the reading/changes in the files watched?

Comment: Have you tried using `select()`?

Comment: Inotify or polling modification time is probably your best bets.

Comment: @hochl `select` checks whether a file descriptor can be read or written, it doesn't check if the descriptor (which might by any descriptor, mostly sockets) has the "source" modified.

Comment: Er, yeah I meant `select()` for the *then checking if I can read any more of the file* part of the question.

Comment: @hochl I'm not completely sure with files, but I think `select` would always say the file is readable.

Comment: I think you're right: `a file descriptor is also ready on end-of-file` (from man 2 select).

Answer (score 3):

Why won't a "tail -f" be sufficient? You could use popen and pipes to handle this from Python.

Answer (score 2):

[￼Generator Tricks For Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) shows how to use [Python generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to solve this type of problem; specifically, monitoring (large) log files. I recommend giving it a read.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it yourself, you might do something like this: If you detect file modification, get the size of the file. If it's larger than last time you can seek to the previous "last" position (i.e. the previous size) and read from there.